# What does precision and scale means in the Oracle NUMBER data type

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, sqldatatypes

I have been reading Beginners guide for oracle DB. The definition for precision and scale are quite confusing.
Book says:

```
number(6,3) 

Oracle allows for 2 not 6 significant digitalis.
```

my problem is, 6 means precision. which means number of significant digits.  so it should accept 6 significant digits. why does the book says it is 2 significant digits

The book i am referring to is [Oracle Database 11g A Beginner's Guide by McGraw Hill Professional, Dec 18, 2008](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Oracle_Database_11g_A_Beginner_s_Guide.html?id=sof6utYpfMYC&redir_esc=y), page number 12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the online Oracle [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#autoId6):

> p is the precision, or the maximum number of significant decimal
>   digits, where the most significant digit is the left-most nonzero
>   digit, and the least significant digit is the right-most known digit.
>   Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to
>   20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits
>   depending on the position of the decimal point.
>
> s is the scale, or the number of digits from the decimal point to the
>   least significant digit. The scale can range from -84 to 127.
>
> Positive scale is the number of significant digits to the right of the
>   decimal point to and including the least significant digit.
>
> Negative scale is the number of significant digits to the left of the
>   decimal point, to but not including the least significant digit. For
>   negative scale the least significant digit is on the left side of the
>   decimal point, because the actual data is rounded to the specified
>   number of places to the left of the decimal point. For example, a
>   specification of (10,-2) means to round to hundreds.