# Number format in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've given a task of exporting data from an Oracle view to a fixed length text file, however I've been given specification of how data should be exported to a text file. I.e.

```
quantity            NUM         (10)  
price               NUM         (8,2) 
participant_id      CHAR        (3)   
brokerage           NUM         (10,2)  
cds_fees            NUM         (8,2)
```

My confusion arises in Numeric types where when it says (8,2). If I'm to use same as text, does it effectively means

```
10 characters (as to_char(<field name>, '9999999.99'))
```

or

```
8 characters (as to_char(<field name>, '99999.99'))
```

when exporting to fixed length text field in the text file?

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661708/what-is-precision-and-scale-means-in-oracle-number-data-type) which gave an insight, but not entirely.

Appreciate if someone could enlighten me with some examples.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the [Oracle docs on types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209)

> Optionally, you can also specify a precision (total number of digits)
>   and scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point):
>
> If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given. If
>   no scale is specified, the scale is zero.

So in your case, a `NUMBER(8,2)`, has got:

- 8 digits in total
- 2 of which are after the decimal point

This gives you a range of `-999999.99` to `999999.99`

Answer (score 9):

I assume that you mean NUMBER data type by NUM.

When it says NUMBER(8,2), it means that there will be **8 digits**, and that the number should be **rounded to the nearest hundredth**. Which means that there will be 6 digits before, and 2 digits after the decimal point.

Refer to [oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/03_types.htm):

> You use the NUMBER datatype to store fixed-point or floating-point
>   numbers. Its magnitude range is 1E-130 .. 10E125. If the value of an
>   expression falls outside this range, you get a numeric overflow or
>   underflow error. You can specify precision, which is the total number
>   of digits, and scale, which is the number of digits to the right of
>   the decimal point. The syntax follows:
>
> NUMBER[(precision,scale)]
>
> To declare fixed-point numbers, for which you must specify scale, use
>   the following form:
>
> NUMBER(precision,scale)
>
> To declare floating-point numbers, for which you cannot specify
>   precision or scale because the decimal point can "float" to any
>   position, use the following form:
>
> NUMBER
>
> To declare integers, which have no decimal point, use this form:
>
> NUMBER(precision)  -- same as NUMBER(precision,0)
>
> You cannot use constants or variables to specify precision and scale;
>   you must use integer literals. The maximum precision of a NUMBER value
>   is 38 decimal digits. If you do not specify precision, it defaults to
>   38 or the maximum supported by your system, whichever is less.
>
> Scale, which can range from -84 to 127, determines where rounding
>   occurs. For instance, a scale of 2 rounds to the nearest hundredth
>   (3.456 becomes 3.46). A negative scale rounds to the left of the
>   decimal point. For example, a scale of -3 rounds to the nearest
>   thousand (3456 becomes 3000). A scale of 0 rounds to the nearest whole
>   number. If you do not specify scale, it defaults to 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
NUMBER(p,s)
p(precision)  = length of the number in digits 
s(scale) = places after the decimal point
```

So Number(8,2) in your example is a '999999.99'

You can see more examples [here](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html#precision).